# Proving that for a sequence $ a_n→a $, $a<b$ if and only if there exist natural numbers $m$ and $k$ such that $a_n < b-1/m$ for all $n≥k $.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am having trouble with the following problem:

Let $ \{a_n\} $ be a sequence of real numbers which converges to the real number $a$. Prove that  $a<b$ if and only if there exist natural numbers $m$ and $k$ such that $a_n < b-1/m$ for all $n≥k $.

I tried using the limit definition, but that didn't get me anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a<b$. Then $b-a>0$. Thus, there is $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $b-a>\frac{1}{m}$. Thus $0<b-a-\frac{1}{m}$. Since $a_n\to a$, there is $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-a|<b-a-\frac{1}{m}$ for $n\ge k$. The last inequality implies $a_n-a<b-a-\frac{1}{m}$ for every $n\ge k$. That is $a_n<b-\frac{1}{m}$ for $n\ge k$.

On the other hand, suppose there are $m,k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n<b-\frac{1}{m}$ for every $n\ge k$. Letting $n\to\infty$, $a<b-\frac{1}{m}$. But the last is cleary $<b$. Done.